# Windows Server: Only allow running one concurrent instance of a program?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I am on a Windows Server 2008 R2. Is it possible to limit the number of concurrent instances of a program/an executable file for a user?

An example: I would like to prevent the users from starting paint.exe if another paint.exe is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a windows service in C# that frequently checks for multiple opened instances and terminates the latter started.

Comment: Sounds like a useful open-source project in the making.

Comment: You are right. I need to check with our MD if its possible to make it OS. I will post the link here.

Comment: Fun. So I could block an important product running by creating a very simple program that does nothing and never closes, and set it to run automatically as a service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the program would need to have this sort of checking built inside itself for this to work. Or then you need to build a custom program launcher script or similar which checks the process list before starting the program.

AppLocker comes close, but even with AppLocker policies you can't do quite what you're after.

Comment: I already looked at AppLocker, but you are right, it does not work with it. Maybe I could write a simple service with C# that checks frequently for a user that has multuple instances running.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not possible, and it rarely makes sense to start with. I have such a program here (Turbo Floorplan) and it sucks - like when I try to replicate a building plan. Can not open 2 documents at the same time.

Comment: That would certainly suck in the use case you mentioned, but there are lots of other types of programs for which having multiple instances open at once would create all kinds of havoc, and as such it'd be perfectly reasonable to prevent additional instances from running. Paint.exe is not a good example of a case where it makes sense.

Comment: Agreed. Then the programmers of those programs should be smart enough to limit their start - it is not like this inot more than a trivial code amount at startup.